# MySql database synchronization

Tags: mysql, replication

I have two different servers for mysql databases. First server is for master database and second server to act as slave. Now i need to synchronization all the changes being done on my master database to be applied to the slave database on real time basis.

Please guide me with all the steps to implement real time mysql database synchronization.

Comment: You should start with the manual first (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-howto.html), and then if you still can't get it, you should ask on serverfault.com, it's more suited for server administration.

Comment: master slave setup is complete.
When i wanted to test that if the changes are being applied from master to slave database on real time basis.
I updated an existing row in a table of my master database. and after checking the 'Slave Status', it produced an error.

Error 'Duplicate entry '11753' for key 1' on query.

isn't replication(real time synchronization) suited for updation on existing records?
please help

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes errors that occur silently/louding on the MASTER will cause the replication to break on the SLAVE (if the query was invalid on the master it will also be invalid on the slave).  There are two solutions: 1.  prevent bad entry on the MASTER by fixing the table (ie required fields) or the logic that allows inserts.  2.  ignore certain errors that occur by modifying the my.ini file on the slave.

On a related note:  The book **High Performance MySQL** is a excellent resource on how to setup replication.